# Convert from C code into ObjC

Tags: objective-c, c, object

I am an experienced programmer in C, yet not objective c. I am trying to help my friend out by giving him this piece of code in objective c. By the way, this is for an iPhone application. I have all foundations necessary, and as you can see, have declared my sound as soundA, using the - (IBAction) method... In addition, the sound is a simply .wav file no larger than 100 kb.

```
- (IBAction)soundA:(id)sender {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, 
        (CFStringRef) @"soundA", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);

    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks so much.

- Kook

Comment: ObjC is a superset of C, so C code is also ObjC code

Comment: `CFBundleCopyResourceURL` has copy in the name so returns memory you own. In your code `soundFileURLRef` leaks as a result. Ditto for the memory associated with `soundID`, as `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` is a 'create' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try changing it from an Unsigned Int to `SystemSoundID`

```
 - (IBAction)soundA:(id)sender {
        CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
        soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, 
            (CFStringRef) @"soundA", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);

        SystemSoundID soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }
```

Or go with a more Objective-C approach:

```
 - (IBAction)soundA:(id)sender {
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@",
                     [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], name];


        NSURL* filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path isDirectory: NO];
        SystemSoundID soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }
```

Comment: Or even `[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"soundA" withExtension:@"wav"]` to collapse the first two lines down?

Comment: Ok, but then if you use [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"soundA" withExtension:@"wav"]... *path will not be declared. How could I get around this?

Comment: Use the second method verbatim to get around it.